# Can we have separate settings for each VS Code instance open?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to have for example different zoom levels for each instance of VS Code open on my desktop.
Right now if I change zooming in one VS Code window, all others get affected as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set all preferences on a per workspace basis.

All you need is `"window.zoomLevel": 1` in a `.vscode/settings.json` file and it affects only the window in this project.

You can read more about the preference system in [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace).

Comment: can't we do it momentarily in any given workspace? For this settings.json needs to be set?

Answer (score 0):

As of vscode v1.86, you can separately zoom in/out any floating windows or other open instances of vscode.  Using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +- triggers.  So no need for a setting like in the other answers.

See this setting - default is enabled, so applies to the active window only:

> Window: Zoom per Window
>
> "Controls if the 'Zoom In' and 'Zoom Out' commands apply the zoom
> level to all windows or only the active window. See `Window Zoom Level` for
> configuring a default zoom level for all windows."