# VSCode: Individual zoom levels for each open VSCode window (Multiple monitor setup with vertical monitor)

Tags: visual-studio-code, zooming, multiple-monitors

I have a 2 monitor setup. One monitor I have setup as vertical as it's easier to read through long code.
The way I have VSCode setup, is that I have 2 separate VSCode windows open for the same workspace (by pressing CTRL + K, then O). One window on the regular monitor, and one for the vertical one. All works fine.

However the issue that I have, is that on the vertical monitor, due to the aspect ratio, the font size of VSCode is too big so I have to zoom out a bit with the built in VSCode zoom function (CTRL +/-). This works fine and I can adjust it so it's perfectly readable. Unfortunately when I zoom, it zooms on all open VSCode windows, including the window on my main monitor. The text there then becomes too small.

How can I have individual zoom levels for each open VSCode window?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77869753/836330 probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a setting `Editor: Mouse Wheel Zoom`. If you turn this on you can zoom with the Ctrl key and mouse scroll wheel, and it only affects the code editors in the current VSCode window.

Answer (score 5):

## Short Answer

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
2. type `editor font...`
3. Choose among the three options.

This gives us individual *editor font* zoom levels per workspace window.

[image]

## Longer Answer

The original question has two bits:

- "have 2 separate VSCode windows open for the same workspace",
- "individual zoom levels for each open VSCode window?"

While VSCode doesn't support individual *window* zoom levels per workspace, it does support individual *editor font* zoom levels per workspace. That's what the short answer provides.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/72011

Comment: The current issue for per-window zoom level is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143663

Answer (score 0):

Dude I am planning to buy a monitor and placing it Vertically so that's why I am confirming how to see the code in the vertical format. Like I use ESLint to prettify my code and I want to set the width of my code to de static so that it should not exceed.

AND on to your problem, there is a setting in VS code to set the font of your code changes with the scroll you should use that.
That will be the bare minimum to work.
Hope this helped.